# How do I find the capillary energy of a wetted/dry ping pong ball?

Tags: fluid-statics, capillary-action

I'm new to capillary forces and I found this statement:[image]

I found Jurin's law or the Young-Laplace equation, but it's always about capillary tube and I would know how to find this  expression.
Regards